# Bash Syntax Colouring

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting

I tried the [fish](http://fishshell.com/) shell, and love the fact that it does syntax colouring in the shell itself: [image: fish syntax colouring]

Is there some way to do this in bash?

Comment: I think you have to actually modify the Bash code in order to do that.

Comment: There is essentially the same question at https://superuser.com/q/304211/980046

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Real time syntax coloring is a lot of work, especially with shells whose syntax is trickier than fish's. Only fish has it out of the box.

Zsh has syntax coloring if you install the [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) add-on.

I'm not aware of any effort to do this with bash.

Comment: [ble.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh) is the only thing I know that comes close to this.

Answer (score -3):

You can edit the bash.bashrc file in the /etc directory. You will want to change $PS1 (primary shell prompt) and maybe $PS2 (secondary shell prompt).

Check out this link for the how-to, it helped me set mine:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Comment: The question is more generic then just prompting.

Comment: I have already customized the heck out of $PS1 and $PS2 ;)

Comment: You've answered a different question, even if well.