# Commands don't turn blue/green in terminal

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, gnome, colors, gnome-terminal

Recently i switched from kali live to a external drive and installed kali with the installer. I updated everything but since the switch my terminal commands do not turn blue anymore. I have searched for answers and tried to fix this but without results.

The steps i tried you can find in the following links:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/774424/terminal-has-lost-its-colours
https://askubuntu.com/questions/517677/how-do-i-get-a-colored-bash

Should look like:
[image]

instead in my terminal `locate` it is just white.

Comment: Why would the output of `locate` be blue?  As far as I know `locate` on the systems I have access to (Ubuntu, OpenBSD) does not color the output based on permissions or file type. Also, none of the files that you list in your screenshot ([don't do that](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)) should be executable as they are not scripts.

Comment: That's the job of a shell. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105030/108618). What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using bash.

Comment: I guess it was not Bash before the switch. I believe [this answer about Bash](https://superuser.com/a/868720/432690) still stands.

Comment: Zsh can do stuff like that: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

Comment: I will check it out thank you very much!

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal execute:

```bsh
sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh your_username
```

Then, re-login and open terminal again, it should be what you're looking for.